# Connect Spring Boot that runs in Docker to PostgreSQL that runs in Docker without compose file?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

To learn Docker I created a small spring boot app that can create/list/update users.

I run a postgresql database on port 5432 and I run my app on port 8081. The problem that when I try to start the container & my app:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I created a network and start the containers like this:

```
docker run --name postgres --network demo-network -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin -d postgres
docker run --network demo-network -p 8081:8081 -d myuser/demodocker
```

My Spring Boot application.properties:

```
server.port=8081
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=drop-and-create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=drop-and-create
```

What to fix to make it work?

Comment: Can you provide the link of the blog that you are following ?

Comment: use postgres container name in application prop instead of localhost . your container name is postgres

Comment: In `spring.datasource.url`, use the other container's name `postgres` as the host name.

Answer (score -1):

I think an even easier way would be to simple change your docker file to include --net=host

```
docker run --net=host <image-name>
```

Once you do that any code inside your container wanting to access postgres is able to use localhost and have it resolve on the host machine, i think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: This generally completely disables Docker's networking layer, and it's not usually a best practice.  Among other things, you lose options like the ability to remap PostgreSQL's port or to hide it from the external network entirely.  There are also known problems using host networking on Docker Desktop, including on non-Linux host systems.